# Perl handling variables in different ways when hardcoded vs red from file

Tags: perl

I'm having issues when trying to use a variable value obtained from an external file with the Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail module.

If I use the variable values hardcoded, they work as expected.

However when I use them as the code below, the Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail module doesn't work correctly. It sends the email, but totally broken (no formatting - Content-Type: multipart/mixed; BOUNDARY="This-is-a-mail-boundary").

Is this the correct way to declare variable in modules?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail;

my $gmail_user = `cat ~/.mailconfig | grep GMAIL_USER | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g'`;
my $gmail_pass = `cat ~/.mailconfig | grep GMAIL_PASS | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g'`;

my ($mail,$error)=Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail->new( -layer=>'ssl',
                                                 -port=>'465',
                                                 -smtp=>'smtp.gmail.com',
                                                 -login=>$gmail_user,
                                                 -pass=>$gmail_pass);
                print "session error: $error" unless ($mail!=-1);
                $mail->send(-to=>'foo@bar.xyz',
                                -subject=>"Subject",
                                -body=>'html body',
                                -contenttype=>'text/html',
                                -attachments=>'./att.txt');
                $mail->bye;
```

Comment: You need to [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) the results of the \`\` operator.

Comment: `unless ($mail!=-1)` is a really confusing way to write `if $mail == -1` :-)